# Prevent Modal Dialogue from Closing Using Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I'm using HTML and Typescript compiling to JS for a project. This also uses Bootstrap. I have a modal dialogue defined as such:

`<div class="modal fade" id="ifsModal">`

This is inside of an HTML file. This modal has a button that allows it to be closed:

`<a class="btn btn-primary mx-3" id="resIFS" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save and Reset</a>`

Hence, there is code (from the `resIFS` function) that gets run when the "Save and Reset" button is clicked; the modal dialogue is also dismissed, via the `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` attribute. However, the TS code inside of the `resIFS` function checks certain conditions, and *if those conditions fail, I would like to prevent the modal from closing.*

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078898) uses vanilla JS but seems to suggest that an `onclick` should be used instead of `data-bs-dismiss`. However, I can't get Typescript to recognize the JS command. E.g. I've tried the hack-y solution of having my function `resIFS` re-open the dialogue through the code, `$('#ifsModal').modal('show');`, but this just throws an error in Typescript so I can't compile it.

How can I write TS code--either via an `onclick` function call to replace `data-bs-dismiss="modal"`, or via the hack-y solution of just re-opening the modal after it gets closed--such that it won't throw an error?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your TS code and the error that you have faced?

Comment: I am simply including this as a line of code: `$('#ifsModal').modal('show');`. The error message says, "Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery`. Would I just want to use jquery in the project? Will that solve my issue? Thanks @Mustafa Reda!

Comment: @Lle.4 Yes, you have to use jquery if `$('#ifsModal').modal('show')` is used. It is jquery's way.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without using jquery though?

Comment: Also, I have now installed jquery using the `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` command, but I have a new error, on the word `modal`: *Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'*

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594423/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-without-jquery-or-bootstrap-js-javascript

Comment: I have now attempted using the `querySelector` in place of the `data-bs-dismiss` attribute to close the modal dialogue. My code is as follows: 
`let modal = document.querySelector("#ifsModal");`
`modal?.classList.add("hidden");`

However, now the modal dialogue is not closing at all.